# How to include socket.h in my c file in Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu

This is my a.c code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <socket.h>


int main(void)
{
    int count[4] = {[2] = 3  }, i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("count[%d]=%d\n", i, count[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it, it shows:

```
a.c:2: fatal error: socket.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

So how do I include it / where can download it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
```

Paths are given relatively to the /usr/include path. So e.g. the socket.h file is under /usr/include/sys/socket.h. You can search for it if you don't know:

```
find /usr/include/ -name SEARCHED_HEADER.h
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it relative to `/usr/include/sys`?